# XCode - Adaptar/preencher ecrã para modo iPad

Tags: swift, xcode, iphone, ipad

Comecei a aprender recentemente a programar em XCode. Após ver alguns tutoriais, comecei a trabalhar numa demo de uma app cujo menu inicial apresenta 5 botões posicionados verticalmente numa stack e uma imagem de lado como é demonstrado na imagem seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o preview em modo iPhone. Não há muito a dizer. Os elementos estão perfeitamente posicionados tal como queria.

No entanto, quando faço preview em modo iPad, a história já é outra:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, os elementos ficam mal posicionados. E o tamanho mantém-se em vez de se adaptar para este ecrã maior.

Gostaria de saber como posso contornar esse problema.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, você fez o auto layout?

Da uma olhada porque o auto layout serve justamente para isso. Adaptar a tela para todos os dispositivos ou no caso de uma stackView vc poderia fazer uma size-class, mas primeiro verifica o auto layout.